# EF LINQ Include with Take

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, include, take

I want to take only 1 client with 3 invoices from the DB.
The code stated below does not give me 3 results(but throws an exception).

> Exception:
>   The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties. Parameter name: path

There is one Client which can have multiple Invoices, one Invoice which can have multiple InvoiceLines.

I want to retrieve one Client with 3 Invoices and the associated InvoiceLines.

What did i do wrong here?

```
    public async Task<Client> Client(int id)
    {
        using (var db = GetContext())
        {                
                return await db.Client.Include(x => x.Invoices.Take(3))
                .Where(i => !i.IsDeleted)
                .Include(c => c.Invoices.Select(x => x.InvoiceLines))
                .Where(x => x.Id == id)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();              
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where clause / Take, the basic idea is the same.

Comment: sorry, i don't see it being the same idea

Comment: Well, the gist is you can't restrict `Include`. Loading entities with partly loaded collections is a hassle.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `.Include` can be used to filter *out* records.

I don't have enough code to verify this does what you want, but I think you can do what you want without using `.Include` at all.

```
var client = await db.Client
    .Where(i => !i.IsDeleted)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);

var top3Invoices = client.Invoices.Take(3);
```

Comment: I've edited my first post, this is not exactly what i meant. Now you can see the return type of the method.

Comment: Hm.  If a client has more than 3 invoices, then I don't think you can make EF act like it has any less.